# How can I generate signature using HMACSHA1 hash algorithm with beanshell in jmeter

Tags: cryptography, jmeter, public-key-encryption, beanshell, hashalgorithm

I need to generate a signature using HMACSHA1 hash algorithm with beanshell scripting in jmeter. This signature I need to put in URL. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in, for example, [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor):

```
String hmacSha1 = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.HmacUtils.hmacSha1Hex("secret", "Message");
log.info("HMAC SHA1 HASH: " + hmacSha1);
sampler.setPath("/you/can/put/your/signature/here: "  + hmacSha1);
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter HMAC SHA1]

The code relies on [HmacUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/HmacUtils.html#hmacSha1Hex(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) class which is a part of [Apache Commons Codes](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) package which is a part of JMeter anyway.

---

However you problem might be deeper that just getting HMAC SHA1 signature, most likely you are trying to test web application protected by [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). In that case you will have to do few more things as bypassing OAuth challenge in JMeter is not that simple. Check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for details.